# Proper security when creating a PHP session that never expires

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

Since keeping a session active for a long period doesn't seem very reliable (when using session_set_cookie_params), it seems like the next best option is to store a cookie along with the session.

When the user logs in, I create a random hash and store it in a database table beside their user id. I then create a cookie and store the hash within it.

If the cookie exists, I extract the hash, do a database search for the user id and automatically log the user in.

If on an open WIFI network, XSS attacked or have a virus/malware, what stops this cookie from being copied and used by some hacker?

What is the best way to keep a session active forever, or until the user logs out?

Comment: where do you think the session id is being stored ??

Comment: Not about php, but very helpful / interesting: http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/how-to-build-and-how-not-to-build.html

Comment: It is stored on the client side, but expires after the browser is closed (usually).

Comment: This is no different than using a cookie to store the session ID (which is already a *nonce* ID). It seems more likely that the session provider is problematic (e.g. is not persisted or times sessions out) or the client clears the cookie. Fix the source; don't add an additional layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to safeguard cookie from xss set HttpOnly flag in cookie. to prevent sniffing use secure ssl connection and set the cookie secure flag too.

Answer (score 1):

Something we do is we use a [custom session handler](https://www.php.net/session.customhandler), and then use a memcached/mysql storage to backend it. Since the session cookies can be set to a longer timeout, we load the data from memcached. if it's not in memcached we load it from the database. If it's in neither, it's a new session. This way you don't have the generate new session IDs (PHP still handles that) but you do have to manage the data inside the sessions.